# Two html drop down list event

Tags: java, jsp

I have two html drop down list, their value are retrieved from the database by using jsp.

```
<%
  String query =" SELECT question_text,question_id FROM questions WHERE id = ?";
   PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
   stmt.setString(1,request.getParameter("QID"));
   ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
    if(!rs.next()) {} else {%>
   <form action="#" method="post">
   <p> First Question </p>
   <select name="currentQuestion">
<%do{%> 
<option value="<%=rs.getString("question_id")%>"><%=rs.getString("question_text")%>  </option>
<%}while(rs.next());}%>
</select>

<%                  
  String query =" SELECT question_text,question_id FROM questions WHERE id = ? AND question id != ? ";
  PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
  stmt.setString(1,request.getParameter("QID"));
  stmt.setString(2,CHOOSEN QUESTION);
  ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
  if(!rs.next()) {} else {%>
  <p> Next Question </p>
 <select name="currentQuestion">
 <%do{%>    
  <option value="<%=rs.getString("question_id")%>"><%=rs.getString("question_text")%></option>
 <%}while(rs.next());}%>
  </select>
  </form>
```

Now, I what when the user choose a specific question from the first drop down list, the value of the second drop down list does not include that question ?
is anyone know how to do that ?

Comment: You can do that using Javascript -- do you have any experience with Javascript (or JQuery)?

Comment: Actually I don't know how to do that with Javascript or JQuery !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You don't set `CHOOSEN QUESTION` anywhere in the code.
2. You forgot he `id` and `name` tags in the `option` element.
3. `CHOOSEN QUESTION` is an illegal name for a variable since it contains a space.
4. You can't do it the way you're trying to do, cause this code runs on the server-side before the user chooses an option. What you probably want to do is load all the options (if there aren't too many of them) and create a JS/jQuery that will refresh the second dropbox on the event `onChange` of the first dropbox (before the user chooses an option - you'll probably want to have the second dropbox disabled)
5. Another thing that you probably want to do is create a `form` which will eventually submit the user's choices to a JSP (server-side).
6. You can also achieve the same behavior using AJAX, you can find an example of how to do it [here.](http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/threads/260185/dropdown-list-onchange-phpmysql)

**UPDATE (example code for changing options using JS):**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" >
<!-- hide

function update(x){
    if (x != "null") {
        if (x == "1") {
            var jumpmenu2 = document.getElementById("jumpmenu2");
            var newOption1 = document.createElement('option');
            newOption1.text = "a"; //HERE You'll use newOption1.text = "<?php echo $db_option_text;?>"; 
            newOption1.value = "1"; //HERE You'll use newOption1.text = "<?php echo $db_option_value;?>"; 
            var newOption2 = document.createElement('option');
            newOption2.text = "b"; // same like above
            newOption2.value = "2"; // same like above
            var newOption3 = document.createElement('option');
            newOption3.text = "c"; // same like above
            newOption3.value = "3"; // same like above
            jumpmenu2.remove(jumpmenu2.length-1);
            jumpmenu2.remove(jumpmenu2.length-1);
            jumpmenu2.remove(jumpmenu2.length-1);
            try {
                // For standard browsers
                jumpmenu2.add(newOption1,null);
                jumpmenu2.add(newOption2,null);
                jumpmenu2.add(newOption3,null);
            }
            catch (ex) {
                // For Microsoft Internet Explorer and other non-standard browsers.
                jumpmenu2.add(newOption1);
                jumpmenu2.add(newOption2);
                jumpmenu2.add(newOption3);
            }
        }
        else if (x == "2"){
            var jumpmenu2 = document.getElementById("jumpmenu2");
            var newOption1 = document.createElement('option');
            newOption1.text = "d";
            newOption1.value = "1";
            var newOption2 = document.createElement('option');
            newOption2.text = "e";
            newOption2.value = "2";
            var newOption3 = document.createElement('option');
            newOption3.text = "f";
            newOption3.value = "3";
            jumpmenu2.remove(jumpmenu2.length-1);
            jumpmenu2.remove(jumpmenu2.length-1);
            jumpmenu2.remove(jumpmenu2.length-1);
            try {
                // For standard browsers
                jumpmenu2.add(newOption1,null);
                jumpmenu2.add(newOption2,null);
                jumpmenu2.add(newOption3,null);
            }
            catch (ex) {
                // For Microsoft Internet Explorer and other non-standard browsers.
                jumpmenu2.add(newOption1);
                jumpmenu2.add(newOption2);
                jumpmenu2.add(newOption3);
            }
        }
    }
}

// end hide -->
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="form1" id="form1">
<select name="jumpmenu" name="jumpmenu" onChange="update(document.form1.jumpmenu.options[document.form1.jumpmenu.options.selectedIndex].value)">
<option value=1>1</option>
<option value=2>2</option>
</select>
</form>
<select name="jumpmenu2" id="jumpmenu2">
<option value=a id=1>a</option>
<option value=b id=2>b</option>
<option value=c id=3>c</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.By CHOOSEN QUESTION I mean the value which has been chosen by user I just wrote that for clarity, and I set the name for select tag why I need to do that for option tag ? can you explain your answer by code example?

Comment: @JavaCrawler in order to implement it, you'll have to read all the options in advance from the DB and update this JS to hold the relevant values respectively.